# How to get the GRAV git-sync plugin working in Azure Websites

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, grav

I have created an Azure App service website and uploaded the [Grav](https://getgrav.org/) CMS. While the app works fine the GitHub synchronization doesn't work.

When trying to use the git sync plugin I get an error message "The GitSync plugin requires the git binary to be installed and accessible in order to work."

I have searched the app extensions but git isn't available there. Is there any way to install the git binary in app service? Or if its already installed what would be the path to the executable i can set in the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

In the git-sync plugin settings you set the Git Binary Path to 
`"D:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"`
*Note the "" due the spaces in the path.*

You can find the paths in the Kudu environment section for your azure app